# Blazor server-side rendering constant data traffic

Tags: .net, signalr, blazor-server-side

I developed a Blazor web application in .NET 8, using interactive server-side rendering. This is deployed to an Azure Web App server, the 'use websockets'-option is enabled.
But I just noticed a lot of data usage (multiple GB's) from this app even with very few users. Then I noticed if I open the website I have a constant data usage of about 370 kbps. Opening the website multiple times just multiplies this number.

As far as I know my application is just 'doing nothing' when not clicking around on the website, so I have no idea why this happens?

The websocket opens correctly, I have no errors in the developer's console. Everything works as it should, except for this constant data traffic. It's not in peaks, it's just a constant traffic like I am streaming something.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for this? Debug your application.  "Everything works as it should", maybe on the surface but under the hood you're running at several thousand RPM.  As far as I know my application is just 'doing nothing': evidently not. You must have page/component/services that are constantly refreshing the UI.  Where is interactivity set? As it stands this is an unanswerable question.  An application that is "just 'doing nothing'" has almost zero traffic.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Looking into the used memory I can see I have a loop somewehere.